# Joining unrelated tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, join

I am working in SQL Server 2005.  I have a table that lists stores and a separate table that lists departments.  There is no key relationships between the tables. My goal is create a query that lists each department for each store.  Ideally the results will be:

store  department
1        candy
1        ice
1        drinks
2        candy
2        ice
2        drinks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the above query with a [cross join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx) (with no relationships in the `WHERE` clause)

```
SELECT d.department, s.store FROM departments d
CROSS JOIN stores s
```

Answer (score 4):

If all stores have all departments, then you might try a CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT store, department
FROM stores
CROSS JOIN departments
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://ideone.com/KErj3

Use JOIN. (The syntax will be a bit different for the creation of the tables since Ideone is SQLite, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` too

```
SELECT s.store, d.department
FROM stores s
JOIN departments d
  ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the same as a cartesian?

```
SELECT s.store, d.department
FROM stores s, departments d
```